# VBA SQL recordsets in forloops

Tags: excel, vba

Currently getting used to VBA inside excel and have been doing some tutorials and practices to get used to the code and have been trying to carry out a simple task without any success.

My task is to compare a range of cells and inside each cell inside this range get the string/text and assign it to a variable. then use this variable in a SQL statement to query a small database and return the result.

I have opted to do this with a for loop which gets the current cells text, assigns it to the variable and then executes the query and pops it into another cell, the problem is that outside out of the loop the code will run fine and i can change the name of the variable and everything is hunky dory, when inside the loop i get an error along the lines of

"RUN-TIME ERROR '3705':
Operation is not allowed when the object is open"

```
Sub NO6_Postcode()

'Connection Variables
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command

' Ranges
Dim myRange As range
Dim nextUsed As range
Dim sqlQry As String
Dim myCell As range
Set myRange = range("A1:A10")
Set nextUsed = range("F1:F10")

'connection to the database via DSN
With cn
    .Provider = "MSDASQL"
    .ConnectionString = "DSN=localhostTest"
    .Open
    End With

For Each myCell In myRange

    sqlQry = myCell.Text

    Set cmd.ActiveConnection = cn
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE name LIKE  '" & sqlQry & "' "
    cmd.CommandType = adCmdText

    Set rs.Source = cmd
    rs.Open

    ActiveSheet.range("F1").CopyFromRecordset rs

Next myCell

End Sub
```

it always through this error when assigning anything to the recordset inside of said for loop

thanks

Comment: Add `rs.Close` after the `CopyFromRecordset` line.

Comment: thanks man pulled it straight away, all i need to do now is to get the 2nd range of cells to loop through

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub NO6_Postcode()

'Connection Variables
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
Dim n as Long
' Ranges
Dim myRange As range
Dim nextUsed As range
Dim sqlQry As String
Dim myCell As range
Set myRange = range("A1:A10")
Set nextUsed = range("F1:F10")

'connection to the database via DSN
With cn
    .Provider = "MSDASQL"
    .ConnectionString = "DSN=localhostTest"
    .Open
    End With

For n = 1 to MyRange.Cells.Count

    sqlQry = MyRange.Cells(n).Value

    Set cmd.ActiveConnection = cn
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE name LIKE  '" & sqlQry & "' "
    cmd.CommandType = adCmdText

    Set rs.Source = cmd
    rs.Open

    nextUsed.Cells(n).CopyFromRecordset rs
    rs.Close
Next myCell

End Sub
```

Although if your query only returns one result you don't really need CopyFromRecordset and if it doesn't you're going to keep overwriting the data.